# Prestashop - Specify shipping for specific price interval

Tags: prestashop

I wish to make to rules/conditions regarding shipping and prices. I have tried several things so far, but with no result. The 2 rules are as following (The currency is Danish Crown - DKK):

1. When you buy products in the price interval 0-500 DKK, you have to
   pay additionally 50 DKK for shipping.
2. When you buy products for (in total) over 500 DKK, there is free shipping.

So far, we have managed to make the second rule (free shipping when buying for more than 500 DKK). But how can I make the first rule?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I have 2 shipping companies to choose from. For each of them, there are some specific rules regarding weight.

I just need to make sure that (regardless of which shipping company it is) there will be added an additional 50 DK when the price is between 0 and 500 DKK. Above 500 DKK, the shipping is free.

Comment: Need that too, do you make any progress ?